# Oracle: XML with multiple nodes with the same name to table

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a XML file stored in a table with a rather strange structure: it can either not contain a certain node, it can contain it once or it can contain it multiple times. In the below example the node "quickFilterValues" is in all 3 situations. I want to build a report with two columns: "fieldId" and count of "quickFilterValues". Can you please help me with a SQL solution in Oracle?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><dataView><fieldOptions><fieldId>1</fieldId></fieldOptions><fieldOptions><fieldId>2</fieldId><quickFilterValues>100</quickFilterValues></fieldOptions><fieldOptions><fieldId>3</fieldId><quickFilterValues>10</quickFilterValues><quickFilterValues>20</quickFilterValues><quickFilterValues>30</quickFilterValues></fieldOptions></dataView>
```

| fieldId | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |

I tried to use

```
create table t(c clob);

insert into t values('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><dataView><fieldOptions><fieldId>1</fieldId></fieldOptions><fieldOptions><fieldId>2</fieldId><quickFilterValues>100</quickFilterValues></fieldOptions><fieldOptions><fieldId>3</fieldId><quickFilterValues>10</quickFilterValues><quickFilterValues>20</quickFilterValues><quickFilterValues>30</quickFilterValues></fieldOptions></dataView>');

select *
from t
cross apply xmltable(
'/dataView/fieldOptions/quickFilterValues'
passing xmltype(t.c)
columns
fo  varchar2(250) path '.'
) x;
```

but this only gets the overall count of "quickFilterValues" and I need it to be grouped by "fieldId".

Comment: Sure, I added the full query. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPATH expression can contain expressions like count():

```
xmltable(
    '/dataView/fieldOptions' passing d.xml
    columns
        fieldId path './fieldId/text()',
        nQuickFilterValues number path 'count(./quickFilterValues)'
        
) t
```

Comment: Thank you, it solves it. I did not know about counting inside xpath, this is one useful feature.

Answer (score 1):

Counting directly in the XPath is great and probably most efficient here, but as a more general case you can use nested XMLTable calls to burrow down into the data too:

```
SELECT x1.fieldId, count(x2.qf)
FROM t
CROSS APPLY XMLTable(
         '/dataView/fieldOptions'
         PASSING xmltype(t.c)
         COLUMNS
           fieldId NUMBER PATH 'fieldId',
           qfs XMLTYPE PATH 'quickFilterValues'
) x1
OUTER APPLY XMLTable(
         '/quickFilterValues'
         PASSING qfs
         COLUMNS
           qf  NUMBER PATH '.'
) x2
GROUP BY x1.fieldId
ORDER BY x1.fieldId
```

| FIELDID | COUNT(X2.QF) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ekFxRC36)